# Google Maps Icon won't show

Tags: javascript, icons, google-maps-api-3

I can't for the life of me figure out why my icon won't show up

```
      function placeMarker(location) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location, 
              map: W.map,
              icon: "/files/icons/maps/beacon_16.png"
          });

          W.map.setCenter(location);
      }
```

When I comment out the icon line, it shows the standard marker, so I'm obviously missing something but the google guides aren't helping in how I'm supposed to format my variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide an absolute URL for the icon attribute rather than relative path.

Comment: yea, that fixes it. I'm not sure but I think it's gotta be online also. Either way it works that way.

Comment: Glad to hear that works!!..Did not get you regarding "its gonna be online"